# IOT Hub AMQP protocol error

Tags: javascript, node.js, azure-iot-hub

I am running the [Getting started with IOT Hub](https://azure.microsoft.com/en-gb/documentation/articles/iot-hub-node-node-getstarted) example, for Node.js:

I followed all steps, but when I run the readDeviceToCloudMessage application, I receive this error in my console:

> name: 'AmqpProtocolError',
>   message: 'undefined:Attempted to perform an unauthorized operation.

Does somebody know what might be causing the error?

Kind regards

URL:

```
var protocol = 'amqps';
var eventHubHost = 'myHost';
var sasName = 'iothubowner';
var sasKey = "myKey"

var uri = protocol + '://' + encodeURIComponent(sasName) + ':' + encodeURIComponent(sasKey) + '@' + eventHubHost;
```

Comment: What does your `client.connect(uri)` line look like? It looks like you're not providing correct MQ url.

Comment: I added my current url, it is not correct?

Comment: It looks like that. Maybe one thing to try is to console.log that uri at the actual location to make sure it is actually making it to the module in one piece - that `undefined` in your message smells. Also maybe try connecting to that URI  manually, from Node shell, just to make sure the host side is ready too.

Comment: Hi, did it work, or are you still having this issue?

Answer (score 0):

One thing comes to mind is, the eventHubHost should contain the value of the Event Hub namespace, not the eventhub name. Can you confirm its the namespace?

Hope this helps!

Mert